# Convert Sentinel GeoTIFF file to JPEG image

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, sentinel-2, jpg

I am facing difficulty converting between Sentinel GeoTIFF file and JPEG file. I used below command i.e.

```
gdal_translate -b 4 -b 3 -b 2 -of JPEG -scale inputimage.tif outputfile.jpeg
```

The problem with this approach is, that if I convert 32*32 TIFF file into JPEG and if the same patch is from 1000*1000 TIFF file and I convert that file into JPEG, then in both cases the same patch looks different in both JPEG files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html):

> `-scale [src_min src_max [dst_min dst_max]]:`
>
> Rescale the input pixels values from the range `src_min` 
>     to `src_max` to the range `dst_min` to `dst_max`. If omitted the 
>     output range is 0 to 255. **If omitted the input range is 
>     automatically computed from the source data**.

The smaller patch will have different min and max values (input range). If you want the smaller patch to look the same same as the larger (or vice-versa) pass the appropriate range(s) to the `-scale` parameter. For example (with totally made up min/max values, you'll need to change these to something appropriate for your data):

```
gdal_translate -b 4 -b 3 -b 2 -of JPEG -scale 0 1234 0 2345 0 4567 inputimage.tif outputfile.jpeg
```

Comment: Got it . According to you what should be the ideal min max value that should work across all geotiff ?

Comment: I can't say, it completely depends on your data.